# Java SpringBoot StackOverflow OneToMany / ManyToOne annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, stack-overflow

I have this MySQL script :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `country`
(
    `id`         int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`       varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `idx_name` (`name`) USING BTREE
);

CREATE TABLE `region`
(
    `id`         int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_country` int NOT NULL,
    `name`       varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT region_country_foreign FOREIGN KEY (id_country) REFERENCES country (id),
    UNIQUE KEY `idx_name` (`name`) USING BTREE
);

CREATE TABLE `city`
(
    `id`        int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_region` int NOT NULL,
    `name`      varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT city_region_foreign FOREIGN KEY (id_region) REFERENCES region (id),
    UNIQUE KEY `idx_name` (`name`) USING BTREE
);
```

and these associated classes :

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "region")
public class Region {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_country", nullable = false)
  private Country country;

  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "region")
  private List<City> cities;
}
---------------------------------------------------
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
public class City {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_region", nullable = false)
  private Region region;
}
```

When I try to retrieve the Region I have a stack overflow Exception. I think this is because the Region has a list of cities and each city in the list has the region which has the list of the cities and so on. I suspect that the error is due to cyclic relations.

Comment: What are you calling so you are getting the error? Does it occur in toString/equals or similar? Can you please share the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Lombok `@Data` creates a default equals, hashCode and toString implementations that will loop between the 2 entities until you get the overflow. And JPA usually uses one or more of those.

Remove it (and eventually add `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, `@Getter` and `@Setter`) and implement your own equals, hashCode and toString where you, f.ex., use the ID instead of the whole Object.

You need to do this in at least one side of the mapping but it might be better for the future to do both.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is due to cyclic relation. You need to add @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation on the parent to break the cycle.